# Using mailkit to retrieve email chains, returns only the first email of the conversation

Tags: c#, .net, mailkit, mimekit

I'm developing an email client using mailkit. I need to display emails as conversations like how it's getting displayed in webmail clients. When I try to fetch data using mailkit for a complete email thread, I'm able to retrieve only the first email of the conversation.

I've checked for `ImapCapabilitites.Thread` value using mailkit and it returned false. So I'm trying to fetch a email thread which has 3 messages and I get only the first message as output and the children count of the thread object is always zero. Please check the below code and let me know if I'm missing any flags which needs to be passed along

```
var summaries = targetFolder.Fetch(requestFilter, MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.Flags | MessageSummaryItems.References); 
var orderBy = new OrderBy[] { OrderBy.ReverseDate };
var threads = MessageThreader.Thread (summaries, ThreadingAlgorithm.References, orderBy);
```

Where `requestFilter` is an `IList<UniqueId>` and `targetFolder` is the subfolder inside inbox in which the mail thread is stored.

Comment: How many messages are being returned in `targetFolder.Fetch()`? Does it contain all of the messages in the thread? I'm guessing it doesn't by the sounds of it. Keep in mind that all MessageThreader.Thread() does is to group the messages together that are part of the same "conversation", it doesn't go out and fetch any more of them.

Comment: Only one message is returned in targetFolder.Fetch() since I've only one uniqueId in requestFilter.

Comment: MessageThreader.Thread() needs all of the messages in the conversation at the very least. If you only feed it 1 message, it can only return 1 message with 0 children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you need *all* of the messages in order to properly thread them.

So your code should look like this:

```
var summaries = targetFolder.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId | MessageSummaryItems.InternalDate | MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.References); 
var orderBy = new OrderBy[] { OrderBy.ReverseDate };
var threads = MessageThreader.Thread (summaries, ThreadingAlgorithm.References, orderBy);
```

You also don't need the `Flags` to thread them, but since you are sorting by `Date`, it may be beneficial to grab the `InternalDate` as a fallback in case a message's `Date` header is not set.

Comment: As suggested, I used the your code instead of mine. summaries return all 5 email threads available in the target folder as MessageSummary objects but the threads return 5 MessageThread objects with all of them returning Children 0 and UniqueId {0}.

Comment: Sorry, you also need `MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId` to make sure the UniqueId of each thread node is not 0. I'd have to see the actual information containedin each MessageSummary to tell you why the threading algorithm isn't threading things the way you expect.

Comment: Since I work for a banking client, I won't be able to post a pic of my watch window. After adding UniqueId flag i'm getting the UniqueId value as expected in thread but still Children as 0. Can you please tell which field data you need from the MessageSummary.

Comment: I would need the `MessageSummary.Envelope.InReplyTo` values and the `MessageSummary.References` values.

Comment: MessageSummary.Envelope.InReplyTo is null and MessageSummary.References is {} with count 0

Comment: Well, then that is why it's unable to thread the messages. Those messages are not part of a conversation that can be threaded using the `References` algorithm. You could try `MessageThreader.Thread (summaries, ThreadingAlgorithm.Subject, orderBy);` instead, perhaps.

Comment: I tried with MessageThreader.Thread(summaries, ThreadingAlgorithm.OrderedSubject, orderBy); Still Children returns as 0.

Comment: Since none of this 2 ThreadingAlgorithm is returning me the email threads, is there any other way in mailkit for me to fetch all the related emails at least as individual emails and chain them manually from my end. Will a search query with subject contains like "RE: Test email" help me retrieve the children emails ?

Comment: It's clear by your last comment that you don't understand how MessageThreaader.Thread() works. MessageThreader.Thread() requires you to first fetch all of the related messages from the server and *then* give them to MessageThreader.Thread() to group them together.

Comment: `ThreadingAlgorithm.Subject` groups messages with identical subjects (minus any `"Re:"` prefixes). Subjects starting with `"Re:"` are grouped as children under the first message without the `"Re:"` prefix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211353/discussion-between-jstedfast-and-nbsamurai).